# Swift error - immutable value '' may not be passed inout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios7, ios8

I updated to the new Swift 1.1. I have an optional variable:

```
let bookingButton: GreenButton?
```

When I try to add this UIView subclass as a subview (self is UIView) i get following error:

```
Immutable value '' may not be passed inout
```

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: use "var" instead of "let"

Comment: Also, if you're trying to pass an implicitly unwrapped optional (ex. UIView!), to a function that expects the unwrapped type (ex. UIView) as an inout parameter, you will get this error message. You must declare that function's inout parameter as the implicitly unwrapped type.

Comment: @PeterParker This helped me a lot. Is there any documentation regarding that?

Answer (score 2):

inout designates a parameter that can be changed by the function. Here you are passing a `let` (an immutable parameter) so this is incompatible. You can change your `lookingButton` from a `let` to a `var` to solve this problem.

As stated in Apple documentation:

> You can only pass a variable as the argument for an in-out parameter.
>   You cannot pass a constant or a literal value as the argument, because
>   constants and literals cannot be modified. You place an ampersand (&)
>   directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to
>   an inout parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the
>   function.